# hr is not getting centered without margin:0 auto

Tags: css

I am trying to vertically center `hr` in a `div` using `absolute` positioning. However, if I do `top:50%`, it's not displayed at the center. Why does that happen? Following is the code for that. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/18597mg2/3/).

`margin: 0 auto` fixes this problem, which is even more puzzling to me since this sets `auto` to left/right margins and not top/bottom margins.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

hr {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.hr-margin-auto {
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <hr class="hr">
  <hr class="hr hr-margin-auto">

</div>
```

Comment: `.hr-margin-auto` also resets `margin-top` to `0`... without it the browser applies `.5em`...

Comment: Tricky to do with classic CSS, and trivial with Flexbox (`align-content:center`)

Comment: @sol stupid question but why does browser applies .5em?

Comment: @JeremyThille you are right. However, I am trying to improve my theoretical understanding of CSS.

Comment: It's because by default the hr element has a margin top and bottom, so it goes to the vertical center with 50% but then it gets pushed down even more by the margin. To center it either remove the margin (like you did) or use transform: translateY(-50%);

Comment: @SKG Probably just to give it a breathing room. If it's used between `<p>` or headings the margins will collapse anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hr` elements have a default margin. This applies to the first of your `hr`s, and that's why it is lower than the one where you defined a margin. If you set `margin: 0` for both (as shown below), they appear at the same position (vertically centered).

In addition, as @Pete pointed out, you have to add `transform: translateY(-50%);` to get exact vertical centering (makes only one px difference in this case, which is why I haven't added it before, but if you want to be precise, it's necessary)

```css
.wrapper{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
 position: relative;
}


hr{
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;

} 

.hr-margin-auto{
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <hr class="hr">
  <hr class="hr hr-margin-auto">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Semantically, `<hr>` element is for thematic breaks.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr)

> The HTML `<hr>` element represents a thematic break between
>   paragraph-level elements (for example, a change of scene in a story,
>   or a shift of topic with a section); historically, this has been
>   presented as a horizontal rule or line. While it may still be
>   displayed as a horizontal rule in visual browsers, this element is now
>   defined in semantic terms, rather than presentational terms, so if you
>   wish to draw a horizontal line, you should do so using appropriate CSS

If you simply need a white line dissecting the box horizontally, an alternative option is `background-repeating-gradient`...

See below, the visual output is the same...

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( blue, blue 50px, white 50px, white 52px);
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

hr {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.hr-margin-auto {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

span {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>With gradient...</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
  <hr class="hr hr-margin-auto">
  <span>With hr...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input sol. I am on mobile now but will certainly give it a try sometime soon.